# Dropdown menu that displays under triggering control

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a dropdown type menu div with tags similar to below. this is not a top menu that only shows up once.

```
<div id=”statusmenu”>
<ul>
<li>menu Item#1</li>
<li>menu Item#2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have multiple buttons in my page that when on click needs to display this menu under the button that created the click event (something like context menu). Is there a more efficient way to do this other than hiding this div under each of my button that shows this div on click Or do Ajax call to server (takes some time) render this content  every time. I am thinking if there is a better solution to hide this div somewhere in page and display it using jquery/JS under the control as the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you cannot make multiple instances of that div because you can only have unique ids. So, you might want that to be a class name instead, such as `class="statusmenu"`. Furthermore, how would you know which elements to drop that menu beneath? Perhaps by marking them with the `class="status"`? If this is the case, then you can use this to apply the menu:

```
$(document).on("click",'.status',function(){
 if($(this).find('.statusmenu').length == 0){
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.setAttribute("class","statusmenu");
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  var li1 = document.createElement("li");
  li1.innerHTML = "menu Item#1";
  var li2 = document.createElement("li");
  li2.innerHTML = "menu Item#2";
  ul.appendChild(li1);
  ul.appendChild(li2);
  d.appendChild(ul);
  $(d).hide();
  this.appendChild(d);
  $(d).slideDown();
 }else{
  $(this).find('.statusmenu').slideUp('fast',function(){ $(this).remove() });
 }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jakVp/

Comment: this is excatly the kind of thing i was looking for instead of building that div every time can it be a hidden div instance i call pull up? but i don;t want it to be hidden under each and every control making my DOM bigger